# Merging tables with unique ID

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have two temp tables.

Table 1 contains all the string info

```
ID | string1 | string2 | etc...
```

Table 2 contains of the int values

```
ID | int1 | int2 | etc...
```

They both share a unique ID.

I need to join them so that it first shows all the the info from table 1 and WHEN there is a matching ID in table 2 to add those values to the end of the table, otherwise when table 2 does not contain that ID to put in a 0, There is never a case when table 1 does not have the ID that is in Table 2

So when the ID is in table 2

```
ID | String1 | String2 | int1 | int2 |
```

AND when the ID is not in Table 2

```
ID | String1 | String2 | 0 | 0 |
```

Comment: Are you not after a `LEFT JOIN` here? What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Comment: I have tried it but what its doing is creating a new row with the int values for when table 2 have the ID

Comment: If you have two (or more) rows for a single value, then you have a one/many-to-many relationship; that is expected behaviour. If you *don't* want that you need to explain what you expect when you have multiple related rows. Sample data, in a **consumable** format (*not* an image), and expected results will help us help you/

Comment: "They both share a unique ID" Is the ID unique in *both* tables? Please also share your attempt which gave you more rows then you wanted, and its results

Answer (score 0):

When you need all rows from left table use `LEFT JOIN` and for controlling value of table2 use `ISNULL` function.

```
Select t1.ID, t1.string1, t1.string2, ISNULL(t2.int1, 0) int1, ISNULL(t2.int2, 0) int2
FROM [table 1] t1
     LEFT JOIN [table 2] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Also it is not called merging tables, but `joining`.